# Xml.XmlDataDocument() obsolete message

Tags: javascript, xml, visual-studio-2010

I am running a simple program in which you enter a user number into a text box, click the submit button, and then the program is supposed to go to a database look up the number you entered and display that rows information. Simple enough.
The problem is I keep getting the error that  Xml.XmlDataDocument() is obsolete. I've googled this issue, which led me to here, but the replacements suggested do not work within my program. 
Also, I have not studied VB and this is for an XML class. 
I've double checked my code for any errors and do not see anything. But, I could be missing the forest for the trees. Would like to have another set of eyes take a look at my code to see if I've missed something, or to offer up a replacement for the Xml.XmlDataDocument() line. 
Thank you in advance for any help you can offer.

Here is the code I am using:

Javascript for the onClick event

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        function btnSearch_onclick() {
            var docSubmit = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument");
            docSubmit.loadXML("<?xml version='1.0'?><request><customerID>" + txtCustID.value + "</customerID></request>")


            var objSocket = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP");
            objSocket.open("POST", "Lookup.aspx", false)
            objSocket.send(docSubmit)
            alert(objSocket.responseXML.xml)

            lblFirstName.innerHTML = objSocket.responseXML.selectSingleNode("//FirstName").firstChild.nodeValue
            lblLastName.innerHTML = objSocket.responseXML.selectSingleNode("//LastName").firstChild.nodeValue
            lblAddress.innerHTML = objSocket.responseXML.selectSingleNode("//Address").firstChild.nodeValue
            lblCity.innerHTML = objSocket.responseXML.selectSingleNode("//City").firstChild.nodeValue
            lblState.innerHTML = objSocket.responseXML.selectSingleNode("//State").firstChild.nodeValue
            lblZip.innerHTML = objSocket.responseXML.selectSingleNode("//Zip").firstChild.nodeValue

        }
    </script>
```

And here is the VB code:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim docReceived As New System.Xml.XmlDataDocument()
        docReceived.Load(Request.InputStream)

        Dim CustomerID = docReceived.SelectSingleNode("//customerID").FirstChild.Value

        Dim myConnection As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim myConnectionString As String
        myConnectionString = "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = " & _
        Server.MapPath("customer.mbd")
        myConnection.ConnectionString = myConnectionString

        Dim strSQL As String
        strSQL = "Select * From CustomerInfo where CustomerID = " & CustomerID

        Dim myAdapter As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(strSQL, myConnection)

        Dim myDataSet As New System.Data.DataSet("CustomerInfo")

        Dim intRecords As Integer
        intRecords = myAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "Customer")

        Response.ContentType = "text/xml"

        If intRecords > 0 Then
            myDataSet.WriteXml(Response.OutputStream)
        Else
            Response.Write("<?xml version='1.0'?><customer><FirstName>Not Found</FirstName><LastName>***</LastName><Address>***</Address><City>***</City><State>***</State><Zip>***</Zip><Phone>***</Phone><Email>***</Email></customer>")
        End If

        myDataSet.WriteXml(Response.OutputStream)

        myConnection.Close()
        myAdapter.Dispose()
        myConnection.Dispose()

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

XmlDataSet is obsolete. As you can see on the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldatadocument.aspx) it may even be removed in the next version of the .NET Framework ([ObsoleteAttribute("XmlDataDocument class will be removed in a future release.")]
). In your case I don't think you need it at all. The easies fix seems to be to use just XmlDocument. I believe you won't have to change anything else in your code but this line

```
Dim docReceived As New System.Xml.XmlDataDocument()
```

to:

```
Dim docReceived As New System.Xml.XmlDocument()
```

Comment: I tried the change and it still does not work. Should I delete the database and then reinstall?

Comment: I answered how to get the a functional equivalent of what you have without getting the "is obsolete" warning. Now, I don't know what "does not work" means here. Deleting the database does not seem like something that will magically fix this.

Comment: "Does not work" means when I enter a number, let's say "3", press the submit button, nothing happens. no data is displayed and no error messages show up.

Comment: With the debugger break after the line you assign the CustomerId variable. Check if the variable is set correctly (i.e. you see the value you passed) - I assume it will be otherwise the query you have would be invalid and you would see the exception. Then step with the debugger (F10) and check your sqluery. Copy it and run against your database and see if you have any results. If you don't check your data in the DB to see what customer Id you would have to use to see any results. Use the debugger (F10) to see what you should expect (either the data from DataSet or the string you write)

Comment: btw. concatenating user input without any validation etc. may lead to Sql Injection attacks.